# Cross Origin Resource Sharing Error: missingalloworiginheader in socket.io tweets streamer app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have been working on a real-time tweet streamer app. Whenever the app tries to fetch new tweets, it throws up repeating errors in the console.

[image: This error pops up multiple times in the console.]

I looked into possible solutions and people suggested using the following code:

```
cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
```

But this error led to another issue and now, my bearer token is not being authenticated.

[image]

I am attaching the code of the server.js file below. Would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand the error and the solutions.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const util = require("util");
const request = require("request");
const path = require("path");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");

const app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const post = util.promisify(request.post);
const get = util.promisify(request.get);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);


const BEARER_TOKEN = process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN;

let timeout = 0;

const streamURL = new URL(
  "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=context_annotations&expansions=author_id"
);

const rulesURL = new URL(
  "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules"
);

const errorMessage = {
  title: "Please Wait",
  detail: "Waiting for new Tweets to be posted...",
};

const authMessage = {
  title: "Could not authenticate",
  details: [
    `Please make sure your bearer token is correct. 
      If using Glitch, remix this app and add it to the .env file`,
  ],
  type: "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication",
};

const sleep = async (delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), delay));
};

app.get("/api/rules", async (req, res) => {
  if (!BEARER_TOKEN) {
    res.status(400).send(authMessage);
    return;
  }

  const token = BEARER_TOKEN;
  const requestConfig = {
    url: rulesURL,
    auth: {
      bearer: token,
    },
    json: true,
  };

  try {
    const response = await get(requestConfig);

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      if (response.statusCode === 403) {
        res.status(403).send(response.body);
        return;
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.body.error.message);
      }
    }

    res.send(response);
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
    return;
  }
});

app.post("/api/rules", async (req, res) => {
  if (!BEARER_TOKEN) {
    res.status(400).send(authMessage);
    return;
  }

  const token = BEARER_TOKEN;
  const requestConfig = {
    url: rulesURL,
    auth: {
      bearer: token,
    },
    json: req.body,
  };

  try {
    const response = await post(requestConfig);

    if (response.statusCode === 200 || response.statusCode === 201) {
      res.send(response);
      return;
    } else {
      throw new Error(response);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
    return;
  }
});

const streamTweets = (socket, token) => {
  let stream;

  const config = {
    url: streamURL,
    auth: {
      bearer: token,
    },
    timeout: 31000,
  };

  try {
    const stream = request.get(config);

    stream
      .on("data", (data) => {
        try {
          const json = JSON.parse(data);
          if (json.connection_issue) {
            socket.emit("error", json);
            reconnect(stream, socket, token);
          } else {
            if (json.data) {
              socket.emit("tweet", json);
            } else {
              socket.emit("authError", json);
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          socket.emit("heartbeat");
        }
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        // Connection timed out
        socket.emit("error", errorMessage);
        reconnect(stream, socket, token);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    socket.emit("authError", authMessage);
  }
};

const reconnect = async (stream, socket, token) => {
  timeout++;
  stream.abort();
  await sleep(2 ** timeout * 1000);
  streamTweets(socket, token);
};

io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  try {
    const token = BEARER_TOKEN;
    io.emit("connect", "Client connected");
    const stream = streamTweets(io, token);
  } catch (e) {
    io.emit("authError", authMessage);
  }
});

console.log("NODE_ENV is", process.env.NODE_ENV);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../build")));
  app.get("*", (request, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build", "index.html"));
  });
} else {
  port = 3001;
}

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: You can not use wildcard origins and credentials at the same time. If you want to use credentials specify domains explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use wildcard origin and credentials at the same time. If you want to use credentials specify domains explicitly.

```
cors: {
    origin: "*", // <-- set origin explicitly.
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
}
```